# Sending mail SMTP, email providers ports and hostnames

Tags: c#, smtp

```
        String[] Sendto = File.ReadAllLines("SendTo.txt");
        SmtpClient X = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        //X.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        NetworkCredential Auth = new NetworkCredential("Someone@gmail.com", "Plainttext password");
        X.Credentials = Auth;
        X.EnableSsl = true;
        foreach (string recip in Sendto)
        {
            try
            {
                MailAddress from = new MailAddress("Someone@gmail.com");

                MailAddress to = new MailAddress(recip);
                MailMessage myMail = new MailMessage(from, to);
                myMail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                myMail.Subject = "Your Test is Done";
                myMail.SubjectEncoding =
                myMail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
               X.Send(myMail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
```

why does this not work? i sniffed the traffic,  I do get a dns reply from smpt.google.com,
but failure to connect to remote server

Comment: Well what *exact* error do you get?

Comment: ex.message == "Failure to send mail"
Inner exception unable to connect to remote server

Answer (score 0):

Modified answer port 993 didn't work...

What worked for me was :-

Note if you have 2 step authentication you may need an app specific password.

```
var mail = new MailMessage();

mail.From = new MailAddress("from address");
mail.To.Add("to address");
mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

var smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
smtpServer.Port = 587;
smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password");
smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
smtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Takes more time but eventually fails with the same execption

Comment: If you're using IIS, check the server event logs.  That will give you lead on where the problem is at.  Might something as simple as a DNS configuration issue on your end.